# Why when childNodes is used, text and comment reutrns?

Tags: javascript, child-nodes

When i use childnode it also return, text and column and then it starts the element.
Can some explain why it does that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/childNodes) (emphasis mine):

> It is important to keep in mind that `childNodes` *includes all child nodes, including non-element nodes like text and comment*. To get a collection containing only elements, use [`Element.children`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/children) instead.